# What is the purpose of associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to this array in forms. I tried to get rid of the associative array in this line

> ("F001"=>"a","F002"=>"b","F003"=>"c","F004"=>"d","F005"=>"e","F006"=>"f","F007"=>"g","F008"=>"h","F009"=>"i","F010"=>"j")

and made it ("F001", "F002" and so on) but program wont work. If I put it back it will work. My question is why it wont work if i get rid of the associative array?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            // move $students into the if statement cause we won't 
            // need it unless they're searching
            $students = array (
                array ("F001"=>"a","F002"=>"b","F003"=>"c","F004"=>"d","F005"=>"e","F006"=>"f","F007"=>"g","F008"=>"h","F009"=>"i","F010"=>"j"),
                array ("albert","berto","charlie","david","earl","francis","garry","harry","irish","james"),
                array (1,2,3,3,2,1,2,1,3,1)
            );

            $idNumber = $_POST['search'];
            // we can use isset here because the student id *is* the key.
            // if it was the value, than we would use array_search() and
            // check if it returned false
            if (isset($students[0][$idNumber])) {
                // array_keys returns the keys of an array as an array,
                // allowing us to find the numerical index of the key
                $studentIndex = array_search($idNumber,array_keys($students[0]));
                // printf basically allows for formatted echoing. %s means
                // a string. %d means a number. You then pass in your
                printf('Student ID: %s<br>Name: %s<br>Grade: %d', $idNumber, $students[1][$studentIndex], $students[2][$studentIndex]);
            }
            else {
                // use htmlspecialchars() to encode any html special characters cause never trust the user
                printf('No student with ID "%s" found.', htmlspecialchars($idNumber));
            }
        }
    ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            Id number: <input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "program wont work" is vague definition. What won't work, would it crash? on which line? would it introduce a weird behavior ? what is it ? what were your code changes that made the program "not work" ?

Comment: @slugonamission in the piece of code above only the keys are used, which means that the associative array *can* be converted to a simple array, that is, unless there is another part of the code that we can't see - which uses them.

Comment: assumnig you have written that code, you should know that if you change the array structure you should also adapt the code to search for the items in the new array structure..

Comment: @LelioFaieta I wouldn't assume that...

Comment: @alfasin it was ironic :)

Comment: @slugonamission only the keys buddy, only the keys ;)

Comment: @LelioFaieta my browser filters out irony... :)

Comment: @alfasin please upgrade from I.E.. 6 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why it doesn't work if you remove it is mentioned in the comments:

```
// we can use isset here because the student id *is* the key.
// if it was the value, than we would use array_search() and
// check if it returned false
```

The reason behind that decision isn't clear from the example, but the letters those keys represent could have a wider meaning to a bigger system, and therefore a decision was taken to make it associative.

As for the purpose of an associative array, it can make searching for specific items simpler, especially in multi-dimensional arrays.  It also can improve readability.

Trying to understand the following would be a pain at best:
`$posts[0][1][0][7][4] = 'value';`

Where as understanding the below is a little easier:
`$posts[newest][1][information][tags][4] = 'value';`

The use of associative arrays above make it easier to see that in an array of posts, the newest post with index 1 has information, and the 5th tag (because of 0 indexing) is 'value'.